# Is it possible to change the color of the section heading and the number associated with it for just one section?

Tags: sectioning, color

Currently, I have

```
\section{{\color{red} Conclusion}} \label{sec:conclusion}
```

This results in the word "Conclusion" to turn into red. But, the section number VI still appears in black. Is there a way to change both the section heading and the number for just one of the sections in a LaTeX document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could get easier help by providing a MWE even if it seems not necessary for you. This is because the section's label seems to be Roman for you but the default article section is not... So, your "template" may be doing several things that we have to know in order to give an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

A MWE would help, but without I suppose something simmilar to this can solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Before Section}

\def\thesection{\color{red}\Roman{section}}
\section{{\color{red} Conclusion}} \label{sec:conclusion}
\def\thesection{\Roman{section}}

\section{After Section}
Test
\end{document}
```

[image]